# Could you please recommend bike lock for long rides and quick stops?

Tags: lock

I have a high-end carbon bike. I do ride long on it, like 100 miles per day.

I am looking a bike lock for quick stops (grab water, food, visit a restroom) therefore requirements are simple: lightweight and secure. Price is not an issue at this point.
Under lightweight I mean less than 0.4kg (less than a 1 lbs).
Under secure - cannot be cut quickly and easily using anything common, like sheer metal cutters or disk cutter.

I have been considering Tigr and Ottolock. Both have failures. Ottolock seems to be the best in the weight category but after I saw how LockPickingLawyer cuts it have serious doubts about it.

I am open to see what is new out there, maybe some exotic materials like titanium-carbon combo.

My bike weighs about 7kg. I will never consider lock that is 10% of the bike mass.

Comment: product recommendations are generally off topic

Comment: A lock in this context is there to purely slow down a thief, or at least make them make noise/attract attention. Nothing will actually be secure.

Comment: Cheap, light, secure, choose one. Even then, battery powered bolt cutters are silent and cut though hardened steel like its butter. Boron steel slows them down a few seconds. Anything big enough to defeat  such a tool you might else well trade up to a steel bike no one would want to pinch because it was so heavy.  (Am I the only one gets the irony of spending thousands of dollars to save tens of grams, then spend more to carry kilograms of locks to keep the bike safe?)

Comment: there is (almost) no lock that can withstand a disk cutter, let alone one that weighs less than 0.4 kg.

Comment: Have you tried Lock Picking Lawyer on YouTube? He's a real lock expert, and he sometimes recommends excellent locks (his recommendation is that it's sufficient to defeat most casual thieves, although a lock-picking professional such as himself can find a way in!)

Comment: You're never going to find an unpickable uncuttable lock that is also lightweight. Consider pairing a mediocre lightweight lock with a secondary security device, such as an Apple AirTag so that you have a chance to recover the bike.

Comment: Obviously, you get a tandem and then take turns with your stoker watching the bike!!

Comment: I want this question to be deleted1

Answer (score 6):

Honestly?  For a nice bike nothing will save it from the malicious+determined.  So avoid giving them opportunities.

Your best bet is to stay on the bike, followed by keeping your hands on it, then keeping it in sight.  As soon as its out of reach/sight, you're more vulnerable to loosing it.

You can spread the work by riding in a group with other people, and take turns going to the toilet or into a shop.

At a cafe stop, sit outside with the bikes (as cyclists, we often have a whiff and don't want to stank up inside.)

I posit that there is no lock that suits your needs; change your processes.

If you're riding alone?  Take your bike into the facilities where possible.  This may mean knowing where good locations are, so plan ahead.   For food, take it with you.

Comment: This is a bit of a set of ideal cases. It can easily be too cold to sit inside, or you may have to queue up inside to order. It's essentially unknown to be able to take a bike into the toilets even at bike cafes. If riding solo, a really light lock allows you to keep a more distant eye on the bike as it buys you time to react to someone hanging around it, but stops still have to be chosen with care. On some long rides I do carry a full lock as I would commuting, on others am intermediate cable lock.

Answer (score 2):

I’d also love a ~200g lock.

Right now I use two different locks, depending on duration and risk.

One is a lightweight cable lock with combination code. Really cheap lock, only 3mm steel cable. The advantage is that it only weighs ~50g and is quite small. The problem is that it’s really flimsy. Only good enough to keep honest people honest and really only prevents someone from picking up and running away with your bike at the café. Even a pair of small cable cutters (or sturdy scissors) would probably be enough to cut it and the combination code is easy to crack.  Example, "BBB MicroSafe"

The other is a U-Lock which weighs “only” 726g. Very sturdy and secure. It’s lighter than most U-locks because it’s relatively short and compact (which is sometimes a problem because it can limit what you can lock it to). Example is "Abus Granit Futura 64" though Kryptonite makes a very similar model too.

I’d really love a lock which bridges the gap between those two. A short, high quality 200g cable lock would be perfect. Something which is sturdy enough that it can’t be cut with a multitool like a Leatherman™ and where you need at least a small bolt cutter or saw to get through. Unfortunately I haven’t been able to find anything like that. Most cable locks are unnecessarily long and covered in thick rubber (which only increases weight).

Comment: One really should not answer by recommending specific products when such questions are explicitly off-topic. I understand the general answers, but not this. This is a road into flames whether Specialized makes better bikes than Cannondale or who makes these lights are the best lights in the world.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава: I’ve always hated the “product recommendations are off-topic” rule. And in this case I only mention the product names as examples so people can look up what I’m talking about.

Comment: @Michael yeah its difficult.   I'll do a minor edit to reverse the order, if you don't like it then hit "revert" in the edit history.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "safe" bicycle lock of any weight, size or form, for a high-end bike.

- High end locks with or without keys can be unlocked with tools and skills not particularly hard to get, as shown by the [Lock Picking Lawyer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZtNEC1uGg4). A thief specializing in stealing high end bicycles at places where those are commonly parked will have no trouble procuring the tools and knowledge.
- To be within your weight allowance, it probably needs to be a cable lock. These can readily be cut by [very small manual](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rphMwxTr54) or even easier with battery-driven hydraulic cutters.
- Just to give you a final hint: the same person uses a [very heavy lock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpVOTEOMRuE) to secure his throwaway $50 city bike (while being able to pick its lock in a few seconds himself), and says he would never let his expensive road bike out of sight for a moment, no matter which lock.

So why use a bike lock at all - mostly to avoid the random theft; I have lost unlocked cheap bikes in my youth which were later found 2km further down the road in a ditch. The thief obviously just wanted to avoid walking 2km and grabbed whatever unlocked bike they found in a stall, and then simply threw it away at his destination.

Some organized thieves probably specialize on driving up to a public stall with a big van (also practical to shield what they're doing from sight), and very quickly grabbing as many bikes as they can. They will go for those which are locked but not against a pole or something (duh...), or the ones with the 99% of "normal" locks which just do nothing against any cutter.  In this scenario, a big beefy lock will help, simply because there will be other cheap locks around which signal to the thieves that it's just not worth it, time-wise, to waste seconds on the beefy one.

And finally, I would assume that there will be some organized thieves who specialize on high-end road or mountain bikes. They will know exactly the locations where such bikes are likely to be out of sight, and target those specifically. They might plan on stealing just one or two bikes a time, which will easily give them enough time to drive up, spend the few extra seconds per lock, and be off.

Finally, forget about securely locking your bike in your garage. Even with a massive ground anchor, battery driven angle grinders or hydraulic cutters make short work of any and all locking solutions known to mankind.

The only practical solution would be to keep your bike close to you and make it difficult/time-consuming/dangerous for a thief to get yours specifically; and hope that they go for the easier targets. If you are going inside to take a pee or get some water, for a few seconds, then any random cheap lock will be the same as any other, to avoid quick opportunistic stealing. Me, personally, I plan all my rides such that there is no time spent out of sight of the bike, period, and very seldomly more than a meter or two away from it. I don't even carry a lock to not get into temptation.

Comment: Your lock only needs to look (emphasis on look, not be ) more secure than the one on the bike next to it.

Comment: Exactly, @mattnz. You don't have to run faster than the bear, only faster than your friends.

Comment: When your rides get really long, in unfamiliar places, you'd have to plan on relieving yourself in public for that method to work, and that's not always an option (also easier for men than women). Luckily my recent 24 hour ride was a team event so we could watch each others bikes, but we couldn't stand over them, so a token lock is useful against someone jumping on and disappearing. Wandering causally to the bikes if someone stops near them is the other half of using a light lock

Comment: Absolutely, @ChrisH. I know relieving yourself in the outdoors is problematic or even illegal in some countries, thankfully not in mine. But the "token" lock from my last paragraph should help with that...

Comment: @AnoE a man standing behind a hedge is simple enough and in a sensibly chosen spot no one should notice let alone mind (here). It gets harder from there - not insurmountable or wild camping wouldn't really be possible

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like the [Abus Bordo](https://www.abus.com/uk/Mobile-Security/Bike-Safety-and-Security/Locks/Folding-locks/BORDO-Lite-6055-Combo). Weights about 1 lbs. Reasonably secure. Sure, your bike might get stolen, but if you pop into the shop for 5 minutes to pick up a snack or just to use the toilet then you'll probably be ok. There would have to be a very opportunistic thief that just happened to be standing there with all the tools just as you pulled up and could make off with the bike in just a few minutes.

As others have said, there is nothing that will be 100% theft proof, but depending on where you live and what the crime rate is like, a basic lock like the one I linked to would be reasonably safe for a quick stop at a store.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answers that *nothing is secure* are technically correct, that isn't necessarily relevant. Yes, you definitely shouldn't leave such a bike unattended for any longer time span, but for the quick restroom stop etc. it's simply very unlikely that any thief with the necessary equipment to quickly and silently break a good lock will come by just in time. That assumes of course the thieves don't *follow you* and wait for an opportunity, but if you're riding alone that seems unlikely even with a super expensive bike.

I still wouldn't trust any cable lock, because these can literally be cut in a blink of the eye with boltcutters that a thief could easily be carrying around all the time in their backpack just in case they stumble on a bike like yours.

It also goes without saying that you should always ensure the bike can't just be *carried out of sight* or put in a car with the lock, i.e. lock it *to* something. That pretty much disqualifies small U-locks and frame locks.

Folding locks and chain locks seem the best option. “Under 0.4 kg” is unrealistic, but a good quality 0.7 kg folding lock should be ok, and these can be compactly mounted on the frame.
Even though chains are heavier yet (≈1 kg), I quite like those. On shorter distance I wear it *around the waist*, which is actually a really comfortable option that makes you hardly notice the weight and keep all the bike's agility, no rattling or anything. The Hiplok brand is all based around this concept. Chains can't be mounted well to the frame, but on long distances I generally have baggage with me and then the lock just double as a baggage strap.

Irrespective of the lock, a lot really comes down to prudence where you can leave the bike. It's good to be somewhere where cars can't approach. It's good to be somewhere crowded, but ideally not *busy* – a place where lots of relaxed tourists hang out, but bikes aren't expected is good. (All of that is easier for MTB than road.) If you can *ask someone* to actually look after your bike for a few minutes, that can be worth a lot, but of course it only works if it's someone who actually has time to pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

In a pinch you can take the wheels off your bike and bring them in with you.  But I usually do this after the person inside asks me to not bring my bike inside and I'm only staying for a 2-3 min tops.   I don't trust locks much.

Answer (score -1):

You could also look into bike insurance. While it is certainly more expensive than a high-end lock (in my experience about 200 euro for a policy of 3 years) it does provide peace of mind.

The insurance mandates that a certain category of locks is used, one of the locks my insurance allowed is pictured below as an example (not a recommendation). It consists of a chain and a framelock for the rear wheel for quick locking.

[image]

As all locks, these are not unbreakable. However, *if* the bike is stolen, the insurance will pay out the original price of the bike if:

- you have paid the full insurance premium
- you still possess all keys (main and spare(s))
- have registered the theft with the police

Obviously these conditions can vary from insurance to insurance, so please double check the policy terms. Note that aftermarket accessories might not be covered by the insurance.

Comment: Does the downvoter care to elaborate?

Comment: Imagine the down vote is because this answer does not answer the question asked. It might help answer the problem the OP has.

Comment: DV was not me, but having struggled for years with insurance, they'd use every excuse not to pay out, including "you didn't take sufficient care of your stuff" and even if they do pay, it will likely be a depreciated amount based on the age of the bike.  I have a low opinion of insurance.

Comment: I too have bad experiences with insurance in general, except with the bike insurance. Both myself as people in my environment have gotten back a new bike without hassle after one was stolen.

Comment: Bike insurance only seems worthwhile for bikes that are barely worth insuring.  For expensive bikes, the policies are expensive (~£500/yr on a £5k bike) and have many hoops to jump through (gold rated lock at all times, special storage requirements at home etc etc)

Comment: @AndyP perhaps it's strongly dependent on the country? I have experience in NL where the premium was around 70 euro/year for a 1000 euro bike (just checked, for a 5k bike that would be 190 euro/year). As stated in my answer, the hoops were minimal: no special storage requirement as long as the certified lock was installed and you could handover both keys.

Comment: Interesting.  I guess it makes sense that policies and pricing are different depending on culture/crime etc etc in different countries.

Comment: Specific bike insurance isn't even a thing here in my country - bicycles are covered under "home contents" insurance.  When I inquired once, the rep thought I was competing and travelling with a fancy bike that was over $10k and therefore too valuable to be covered by home-contents.   Rules vary so much around the world.